# Разбить список на парные элементы не через zip

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = [[0, 0, 1, 2, 3],[3,666]]
result = []
    for cort in list1:
        if len(cort)!=2:
            result.append(list(zip(cort, cort[1:])))
        else:
            result.append(cort)
print(result)
```

***Вывод***

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)],[3,666]]
```

Можно как- то переделать без `zip()`, он мне возвращает список кортежей, а мне нужен список списков.

***Вывод***

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]],[3,666]]
```

Comment: а зачем сразу писать вопрос когда возникает проблема? не проще ли сначала поискать решения самому ? буквально 1 ссылка в гугле https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372399/zip-with-list-output-instead-of-tuple по фразе  zip to list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если использовать `map` с функцией `list`, то будет ожидаемый результат:

```
result.append(list(map(list, zip(cort, cort[1:]))))
```

Но, думаю, красивее будет без функционального стиля:

```
result.append([[x, y] for x, y in zip(cort, cort[1:])])
```

Comment: А есть возможность потом собрать обратно список списков `[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]],[3,666]]` до изначального вида `[[0, 0, 1, 2, 3],[3,666]]`?

Comment: @Nommad, наверно, можно. Если не сможете, то создайте отдельный вопрос :)